# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable - main()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need help in understanding and resolving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./pwdCracker.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "./pwdCracker.py", line 45, in main
    testPass(cryptPass,user)
  File "./pwdCracker.py", line 22, in testPass
    cryptWord = crypt.crypt(word,insalt)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

It occurs every time I run this code:

```
def main():

    parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A simple brute force /etc/shadow .')
    parse.add_argument('-f', action='store', dest='path', help='Path to shadow file, example: \'/etc/shadow\'')
    argus=parse.parse_args()
    if argus.path == None:
            parse.print_help()
            exit
    else:
            passFile = open (argus.path, 'r')
            for line in passFile.readlines():
                    line = line.replace("\n","").split(":")
                    if not line[1] in [ 'x', '*', '!']:
                            user = line[0]
                            cryptPass = line[1]
                            testPass(cryptPass,user)
if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a file named `crypt.py` in your local directory, and in it you have a line `import crypt`. This is a circular import and masks the standard library `crypt` module.

Find it with:

```
import crypt; print(crypt.__file__)
```

at the top of your script, then rename that file.

Comment: I appreciate your comments. I just did that and it's working again.